# Adding product price without VAT

Tags: php, magento

When adding or editing a product inside the Magento administrator the prices has to be entered as a price including VAT. For our purposes it would be a lot easier if we could enter the prices excluding VAT.

It doesn't seem this is a configurable option of Magento. What is the best way to change the admin so we can use it as proposed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System -> Configuration -> (Sales) Tax -> Calculation Settings -> Catalog Prices -> Excluding Tax
HTH

Comment: I am sorry to ask in this thread but I have the same problem. I would like to display the actual text 'excl VAT' next to my prices so that the customers know its excluding vAT. Any ways of doing that?